# void* data type in linked list?

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I am trying to implement key, value linked list so I declared:

```
template<class S, class T>
class node {
public:
    S key;
    T value;
}
```

Now I want to support this function:

```
StatusType Add(void *DS, int key, void* value)
{
    // key - the key of the node
    // value - pointer to the value of the node
}
```

I'm confused about which linked list to use, the key should be int but what should be the value?

Comment: Why `void*` instead of `template<class S, class T> Add(???, S key, T value);`? What is `DS`?

Comment: The `node` class is strongly typed while the `Add()` method is untyped. It's an odd combo. Can you explain why and how you are mixing C++ and C style code together?

Comment: It's also unclear what the mystery `void* DS` argument is. Does that somehow include type information?

Comment: when you say "Now I want to support this function" do you actually mean "Now I want to impement a generic function to add a `node` to a linked list made of from `node`s" ?

Comment: Since you have a _key/value_ pair, is this linked list some kind of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to implement the `StatusType Add(void *DS, int key, void* value)` function so it can be used by C code, but your own implementation can use C++.

In that case, the obvious choice would be `std::map<int, void*>`. Linked list types don't have keys.

Answer (score 1):

To store the void* datatype, you need to use the - wait for it -  void* data type. Like this: `node<int, void*>`.